# Elementary question on the expected value of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'll start by saying I have never studied probability before, so forgive me if this question is very basic.

Anyway, let $T$ be the set of *all* real triplets $(a,b,c)$ so that $1 \leq a \leq 2$, $1 \leq b \leq a^3$, and $c = a+b^2$, and let $(x_a,x_b,x_c)$ be a triplet chosen uniformly randomly from $T$.

**I have a few questions. My first:** what is the expected value of $x_a$? Intuitively, I think "the larger the value of $a$, the 'more' triplets in $T$ there are having the value $a$, so it cannot be $1/2$." That is, suppose $a=1.2$, then $b$ can assume values between $1$ and $1.2^2$, an interval larger than the range of values it could assume if $a$ were less then $1.2$. In this sense, if I want to determine the expected value of $x_a$, I need to account for the varying quantity $a^3-1$. But I am not sure how.

**My second question:** How may I determine the expected value of $x_c$?

**Edit:** To clarify, when I say that a triplet is chosen uniformly randomly, I mean that the joint distribution of $x_a$ and $x_b$ has constant density.

Comment: It would very much depend on $T$.

Comment: @joriki Why should it? The expected value of $x_a$ should be directly $1.5$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @joriki What exactly would it depend on? I'm not sure if I made this clear, but $T$ contains *all* triplets of real numbers defined above. That is, if $ 1 \leq a \leq 2$ and $1 \leq b \leq a^3$, then $(a,b,a+b^2) \in T$. The set doesn't vary.

Comment: No, you hadn't made that clear. It said "a set of real triplets" before your recent edit.

Comment: @sudeep5221: In the original formulation of the question (which you commented on), there was no reason for the expected value to be $1.5$. For instance, for $T=\{(1,1,2)\}$, the expected value of $x_a$ would have been $1$.

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse: In the new formulation, where $T$ is *the* set of *all* triples that fulfill the inequalities, it's not clear with respect to which measure you want to choose uniformly from $T$. Since there is a functional relationship between $a$, $b$ and $c$, only two of them can be chosen independently, and the uniform measure will be different depending on which pair you choose. I suspect that you may mean the uniform measure for $a,b$; if so, you should make this explicit.

Comment: Also, the interpretation I would assume in the current formulation is that you do mean the joint uniform distribution for $a$ and $b$ (for which the marginal distributions of $a$ and $b$ would not be uniform). If you mean that $a$ is chosen uniformly on $[1,2]$ and $b$ is chosen uniformly on $[1,a^3]$, then that, too should be made explicit.

Comment: @joriki Ah I see. Makes sense. I implicitly assumed $T$ to be the set of all triplets. In the previous case, it would certainly depend on $T$.

Comment: @joriki I made an edit according to your advice. However, when you say "I would assume in the current formulation is that you do mean the joint uniform distribution for $a$ and $b$... If you mean that $a$ is chosen uniformly on $[1,2]$ and $b$ is chosen uniformly on $[1,a^3]$, then that, too should be made explicit." Are those two things not the same? I am sure what 'joint uniform distribution' is.

Comment: By "joint uniform distribution", I meant the distribution that is uniform in the $(a,b)$ plane; that is, there would be a constant density in the region $1\le a\le2$, $1\le b\le a^3$ of the $(a,b)$ plane, with equal areas being equally likely to be selected. That's a different distribution than you get if $a$ is uniform on $[1,2]$ and $b$ is uniform on $[1,a^3]$. In the joint uniform distribution, $a$ is more likely to take larger values, because there are "more" $b$ values for larger $a$ values.

Comment: @joriki Oh! That is exactly what I want. Is it proper to simply state that $a,b$ are 'chosen from a joint uniform distribution'?

Comment: You can put @DescartesBeforetheHorse but you Kant make it drink: Now that I'm thinking about it, I think "uniform joint distribution" would be better. Or you could say that the joint distribution of $a$ and $b$ has constant density.

Comment: @joriki I editted accordingly. Still not sure what the expected value of $x_c$ is though...

Comment: I just realized I dropped the factor $\frac13$ in the expected value of $b^2$; I corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t quite see why you introduced the separate triples $a,b,c$ and $x_a,x_b,x_c$; I’ll use $a,b,c$ to keep the notation simple.

The expected value of $a$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\int_1^2\mathrm da\int_1^{a^3}\mathrm db\,a}{\int_1^2\mathrm da\int_1^{a^3}\mathrm db}
&=&
\frac{\int_1^2\mathrm da\left(a^3-1\right)a}{\int_1^2\mathrm da\left(a^3-1\right)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\frac15(32-1)-\frac12(4-1)}{\frac14(16-1)-(2-1)}
\\
&=&
\frac{94}{55}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The expected value of $b^2$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\int_1^2\mathrm da\int_1^{a^3}\mathrm db\,b^2}{\int_1^2\mathrm da\int_1^{a^3}\mathrm db}
&=&
\frac{\frac13\int_1^2\mathrm da\left(a^9-1\right)}{\int_1^2\mathrm da\left(a^3-1\right)}
\\
&=&
\frac13\cdot\frac{\frac1{10}(1024-1)-(2-1)}{\frac14(16-1)-(2-1)}
\\
&=&
\frac{2026}{165}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

By the linearity of expectation, the expected value of $c=a+b^2$ is the sum,

$$
\frac{94}{55}+\frac{2026}{165}=\frac{2308}{165}\;.
$$

Comment: In general, if $c=f(a,b)$ is an integrable function over our region $T$ ($1 \leq a \leq 2$, $1 \leq b \leq a^3$) is there a general approach to find the expected value of $c$? I would assume we are not always evaluating $f$ at the expected values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Or would it just be the volume integral of $f$ over $T$ divided by the area of $T$?

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse: Exactly. In fact that was already the case here; the expected value of $b$ doesn't appear, it was that expected value of $b^2$ that was calculated. The only less-than-general aspect here was that the expected value of a sum can be calculated as the sum of two expected values because of the linearity of expectation, whereas e.g. if it had been $a\cdot b^2$ instead of $a+b^2$ then we'd need a single calculation for $a\cdot b^2$, we couldn't just multiply the expected values for $a$ and for $b^2$.